# How to initiate drawing dots when connection is made to db in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am working with a d3 scatterplot. I have made a successful connection to the database:

```
.on("click", function(d) {

            d3.json("connection2.php?paperID="+d.ID_to, function(error, data) {

                var citationList = ""
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    citationList = citationList + +d['ID'];

                    console.log(citationList);

                    })
            })

        })
```

This works perfectly and I can see the correct data displayed in the console. Now I want to use this data and draw it as a dot on the graph. This is the code for drawing the dots.

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".dot")
                        .data(data)
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr("class", "dot")
                        .attr("r", 3.5)
                        .attr("cx", xMap)
                        .attr("cy", yMap)
```

This also works but my problem is how to connect these two elements as in how to trigger drawing the the dots with the data collected from the connection. 
Any feedback greatly appreciated I am new to d3.

Comment: Surely you just run the function which creates the dots when you successfully get data from the database ?

Comment: It will draw the first element in the list then give this error. And first dot isnt even in the right position `Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cy="NaN"`

Comment: So youre missing data or it's in the wrong format. To solve this for you we need more code, for example what is xMap and yMap ? Maybe create a fiddle so we can take a look :)